# I am unable to make sense of this sentence:

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, phrase-usage, sentence-structure

I am unable to make sense of the highlighted sentence in the attached picture, especially the phrase, "leading note" if it's really used as a phrase. Unfortunately, the context doesn't help much as the former and the latter, both are cited sentences.

> Robert Boyle exemplifies in most interesting fashion all the leading
> intellectual currents of his day ; every important or prevalent
> interest and belief occupied some place in his thinking and the
> conglomeration was harmonized with considerable success around the
> foci  of his two most dominant enthusiasms, experimental science and
> religion. Boyle defines philosophy as "a comprehension of all those
> truths or doctrines, which the natural reason of man, freed from
> prejudices and partiality, and assisted by learning, attention,
> exercise,xperiments, etc., can manifestly make out, or by necessary
> consequence deduce from clear and certain principles. **His conception
> of the leading note of the scientific current of which he formed a
> part appears at the end of an attack on the highly dogmatic and
> metaphysical character of the scholastic philosophy.** “ Our great
> Verulam attempted with more skill and industry (and not without some
> indignation) to restore the more modest and useful way practised by
> the ancients, of inquiry into particular bodies without hastening to
> make systems, into the request it formerly had ; wherein the admirable
> industry of two of our London physicians, Gilbert and Harvey, had not
> a little assisted him. And I need not tell you that since him
> Descartes, Gassendi, and others, having taken in the application of
> geometrical theorems for the explanation of physical problems ; he and
> they, and other restorers of natural philosophy, have brought the
> experimental and mathematical way of inquiry into nature, into at
> least as high and growing an esteem, as it ever possessed when it  was
> most in vogue among the naturalists that preceded Aristotle.
>
> **"The metaphysical foundations of modern physical science" E.A. Burtt · 1925**

[Full text (Archive.org)](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.179345/2015.179345.The-Meta-Physical-Foundations-Of-Modern-Physical-Science_djvu.txt)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.  Transcribe the part that is important.

Comment: You should also specify where the quoted text is from. The style seems very old.

Comment: The phrase "leading note" has a [meaning in music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading-tone), meaning a note that is expected to "resolve" to a nearby note by rules of melody. I wonder whether this is part of an extended metaphor since the author used "harmonized" earlier. Ultimately, we're probably missing the important part of Boyle's quote, since the author says the "leading note" comes "at the end."

Comment: or the *conception* comes at the end i.e. "The conception" is of a leading note; the description of this conception appears "at the end."

Answer (score 2):

I suggest these meanings for "note" in that passage:
[Merriam-Webster *note*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/note)

> 2 a : a characteristic feature (as of odor or flavor)
> b : something (such as an emotion or disposition) like a note in tone or resonance
> *a note of sadness; end on a high note*

Then, a **leading note** is a feature or aspect that stands out above others.

It's worth mentioning that while the text dates from 1925, the quoted part from Robert Boyle dates from about 1670. It's very old-fashioned.

Comment: Agreed; the sentence is saying that the definition of philosophy Boyle came up with was the "leading note", i.e. the foundation and key aspect, of the school of scientific  thinking of the era that he was a part of. You can find Boyle's full text here: https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Works_Of_The_Honourable_Robert_Boyle/aUxTAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22can+manifestly+make+out%22&pg=PA168&printsec=frontcover

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That seems to be the link to Burtt's 1924 text; mine was to Boyle's text that Burtt is quoting (so as to see the full context).

Comment: I had seen this meaning of the "note", but I am still unable to make sense of this; "His conception of the leading [characteristic] of the scientific current of which he formed a part".

Comment: @Showsni I don't think that "his conception of the leading note" means "his definition of the philosophy was the leading note".